# Subversion Apache Ubuntu - Remote Access?

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, svn, internet

Okay, a couple days ago I built a bare bones kit into a machine. I've been running through tutorials to get it to work and right now I've gotten as far as making it available in my lan, hooray!

However, I cannot access the repositories remotely. Any machine on the lan can easily access it through the hostname or, using 'outbound ip/hostname' or 'outbound ip/machine ip'. The machine can be pinged from a remote, non-lan machine and responds. I just can't get anyone into it outside of my lan.

I've been trying to figure it out but I'm lost. I'm breaking a few rules and if any of these would be my problem, please indicate.

- I don't think I have a static IP (However I check my outbound IP whenever I do testing, is that not enough? It has stayed the same for 5+ days)
- I have not discussed this set-up with my service provider (Does Optimum Online block port 80? If so, can I just switch apache to listen on a different port?)
- I am in the DMZ of my router. This is what allowed it to be pinged remotely. For security reasons the machine that is in that zone is turned off most of the time until I can get it locked down.

Edit:

- HTTP protocol (I was planning on changing once I had figured out this issue)

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's just a couple of words I could google to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Tortoise SVN does not allow access remotely, but it does within the LAN as well.

Comment: What protocol are you using for SVN access? SVN? SVN+SSH? HTTPS?

Comment: HTTP, until I figure out how to make it available outside my LAN. Then I was going to switch to HTTPS. I'd like to point out that none of my apache default sites are available outside the lan either.

Comment: Are you sure that the PING requests are being answered by your Ubuntu system and not the router?

Comment: The router was previously not answering ping requests (they would just time out) until the server machine was brought into the DMZ. However, if there is a way to verify this, I'd like to find out how.

Answer (score 1):

Some steps:

1. Check the Apache log files (**/var/log/apache2/** according to LapTop006 in comments) to see if **any** web requests reach the Web Server. If not, something is blocking the traffic it before it reaches Apache.
2. In this case it is:

   - (a) Local firewall on Ubuntu only allows port 80 from local network (?)
   - (b) Router is blocking incoming traffic on port 80
   - (c) Router is not **forwarding** port 80 to your Ubuntu server when traffic is from the outside world?
3. Check the logfiles (if there is any) of the router for dropped packets coming in from the internet. Look for traffic with "Destination Port 80" being dropped on the way in.
4. If the router logs are clear, consider creating a temporary rule **blocking** incoming port 80 to make sure that port 80 traffic **is** reaching your router.
5. That's all I got.

Good luck.

Comment: Apache logs on debian based systems is `/var/log/apache2/`

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that some ISP services actively block access to port 80 (and 25, and others...) in a vain effort to prevent you from running your own servers, right?  They would much rather that you upgrade to a "business-class account" for that reason...

Your issue could be as simple as your ISP filtering your traffic.  I don't see any mention of who it is; until you provide that, any effort to answer the question will still be hit-and-miss.